# Word meaning "influences of / effects of"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that is a noun meaning "influences of" or "effects of"?

For example, suppose I had a table like this:

```
Property         |    XYZ  
----------------------------------
Skin color       | Cultural perceptions, ease of sunburn
----------------------------------
Moisture content | Rate of food spoilage, hardness
----------------------------------
Wavelength       | Ability to transmit through different media, photon energy
```

This is an awful contrived example, but for each term in the "Property" column, the corresponding content in the "XYZ" column notes what kinds of things the property influences or affects.

My problem is what to put instead of "XYZ".

I don't like "Affects" or "Influences" as verbs, because they have other meanings as nouns. "Impacts" also has noun and verb form.

The word "Implications" is close to what I'm looking for, but not quite.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Parameters influenced",  but I don't like the term myself.

Comment: "Results" kind of fits

Comment: "Effects" seems to work

Comment: “Dependencies” may help.

Comment: Hmm. What if I put an adjective in front of Effects? (example: "Observable effects", "Tangible effects") to counteract the ambiguity between noun and verb?